# How to create a Javascript Node in Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, domdocument

Simple question, I essentially want to do something like the following, but in "angularness"

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

I have the appendChild part, I just don't know how to create an element that is of type Node and didn't find anything on it. I know you can create an element using `angular.element("<div></div>")` however the problem with that is that is not of type Node and the appendChild method will not accept it.

Comment: Why are you doing this? You probably don't want to be appending elements like that using Angular.

Comment: Creating a dynamic directive, that appends some html depending on the data. It's not a crazy difficult task, so I'm just making something custom like this.

Comment: And actually, to be more specific, I've made a directive using this method before, however, I managed to never need to append something to a childNode, where something like this would be needed.

Comment: @DanielJamrozik You probably want to bind a repeater to an array in your model, then add/remove elements to that (which will in turn add/remove nodes in the document).

Comment: Sounds like you could use something much simpler like `ng-if` but if you're using very dynamic data you may have to use `$compile`

Comment: `angular.element(document.body).append("<div></div>")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Angular's jqlite you would do the similar thing as with jQuery.

```
var p = angular.element("<p>")[0]; // now it's node
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

And conversely

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
angular.element(document.body).append(angular.element(p));
```

If you've got `p` from the outside and don't know exactly if it is DOM or jqLite element, use `angular.element` wrapper for it anyway (again, as you would do with jQuery).